# I want to get list where invoice _category is service please help?

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, caml-query, caml

[image]

I want to get the list items where `invoice _category` is equal to "Service".

Please help?

Current code:

```
camelQuery.Viewxml = "<View><Query> <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Invoice_Category'/> <Value Type='Text'>Service</Value></Eq></Where><Query></View>"
```

It throws an error of string constant.

Comment: What is the data type of your column/field (invoice _category)?

Comment: The last <Query> element should terminate the first one -- it is missing a forward slash...

Comment: Yes, there are some syntax errors in CAML. refer below answer for complete query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your CAML in below format:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Invoice_Category'/>
                <Value Type='Text'>Service</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

**Note**:

1. In CAML query you need to use internal name of your column/field.

[Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Complete Code**:

```
string siteUrl = "http://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName";  
  
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);  
SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");  

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();  
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Invoice_Category'/><Value Type='Text'>Service</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";  

ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);  

clientContext.Load(collListItem);  
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  

foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem) {  
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} \nTitle: {1}", oListItem.Id, oListItem["Title"]);  
}
```

**Update from Comments**:

Also, from the screenshot you attached in your question, I can see that the value in your column is "Service Invoice" and not just "Service". So in that case you might need to use `Contains` instead of `Eq`. check below query:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name='Invoice_Category'/>
                <Value Type='Text'>Service</Value>
            </Contains>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

**Reference**: [Query schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema).

Comment: options strics on disallows implicit conversions from system.xml.linq.xelement to string error is there

Comment: Try using the code given in my updated answer. let me know if this works for you. Or you can add the complete code you are using to get list items to your question.

Comment: ',' expected error

Comment: actualy we have an invoice list in which to get the information of the service from the invoice category coloumn

Comment: At which code line you are getting this error? Also, what is the data type and internal name of your "Invoice_Category" column? Can you please add the screenshot of column settings for Invoice_Category column? (Go to list settings-->navigate to columns section-->click on the Invoice_Category column name-->take screenshot-->Edit your question-->attach image).

Comment: plz check the edit question

Comment: I am suspecting this might be a lookup column? If so, you need to adjust the query. Details can be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/fieldref-element-query

Comment: This is not the column settings screenshot. I think this is a list view screenshot of the column values. Also, the value is "Service Invoice" and not "Service". So you might need to use "Contains" instead of "Eq".